# Can someone explain the math/rationale behind this behavior?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

so I have this node network that gives me straight lines from the wave texture, using the X-vector component:

[image]

I was thinking if I used the Y vector component for the Scale of the wave texture, I'd get wave lines that get wider or narrower, but instead I get a curve.  Why is this curved instead of actually affecting the scale as I hoped?

[image]

If I just output Y as a color, it seems to increase from left to right as I expect:

[image]

What am I missing?  Thanks!!

Comment: the shape doesn't really matter in this case, but it's just a single flat quad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let see how waves is generated.

It takes your x coordinate (X will be go down like in your view), then multiples by scale value in your case it is 1:

Numbers 1,2,3 ets will be white, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 ets - dark (real algorithm uses Sin function to convert this number to lightness, but I get this because it simpler to view):

[image]

Usually, y coordinate uses too, but you separate coordinates and get only first one, so I set Y coordinate as scale because it simpler to view.

Now let see, that happens if i set Scale to 2:

[image]

As you see, waves gets smaller. If i make the scale bigger I will not see waves, just because my grid haven't enough resolution for this. So instead I try to put Y coordinate as scale to see that it will do:

[image]

So, you see this effect because scale is not regular and waves gets smaller and smaller while scale gets bigger across y-coordinate.

Comment: this is very very helpful.  I want to study it more but it makes a lot of sense!  Thank you very much!